# properties file to configurate storm topology and kafka on hortonworks

Tags: java, hive, hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm working on a Real Time data Ingestion in Hbase and Hive using Storm on hortonworks, and I developped the storm topology to receive data from kafka brokers the topology is submitted i can see my `kafkaspout` and my two bolts but , I don't know why my `kafkaSpout` doesn't consume messages from Kafka Brokers but when i visualize the topology : `0%` data has been consumed!!

I also have an error on my `hdfsbolt`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error preparing HdfsBolt: Permission denied: user=storm, access=WRITE, inode="/infos-cliens-v4/staging/infosClientshdfsBolt-4-0-1462472414665.txt":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x at
```

My @ip is `192.168.1.78`

I think I have to fix the properties file but i don't know how:

```
#Broker host
  kafka.zookeeper.host.port=localhost
    #Kafka topic to consume.
    kafka.topic=TOPICINFORMATIONSCLIENTS
    #Location in ZK for the Kafka spout to store state.
    kafka.zkRoot=/infos_clients_sprout
    #Kafka Spout Executors.
    spout.thread.count=1

    #hdfs bolt settings
    hdfs.path=/infos-cliens-v4
    hdfs.url=hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020
    hdfs.file.prefix=infosClients
    #data will be moved from hdfs to the hive partition
    #on the first write after the 1st minute.
    hdfs.file.rotation.time.minutes=1

    #hbase bolt settings
    hbase.persist.all.events=false


    PLZ Help me
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user is

> storm

but the dir for writing is owned by HDFS.
So change the user permission of that directory and make storm as the user using

> chown

command.

First check using java code if you are able to connect to Hbase. Then test that same logic in Storm topology.

Comment: Thanks I maked storm as the user but My kafka spout doesn't consume messages I don't know why

Comment: Double check correct topic name, IP or Hostname etc...  Did you check Storm and Kafka logs for error messages ? . Also see STORM UI for any clues. Thx

Comment: @Property zk.connect is not valid                                                                  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

Comment: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation                                                                                        
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: 16/05/07 10:27:09 WARN common.AppInfo$: Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: please check http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201403.mbox/%3CCAFEpjOq3bW6NG55Ov6WX7rPLrZsO7CCpO2oxShNv1oG4iG1RzA@mail.gmail.com%3E  in activateOptions() method in which this propery was mentioned. and also please delete the above text in answer text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Property zk.connect is not valid                                                                  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".                                                                                     
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation                                                                                        
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.                                                                   
16/05/07 10:27:09 WARN common.AppInfo$: Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException              

  enter code here
```